# Data sanitization for user registration and user login

Tags: validation, wp-create-user, user-registration, sanitization

What kinds of data sanitization I have to do if I make a front end login and registration system for wordpress users?

1. For login function [`wp_signon()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon) should I escape the data for
   possible sql injection or wordpress will automatically do it for me?
2. For registration I have found two function so far [`wp_insert_user()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user) and [`wp_create_user()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user) and for updating user [`wp_update_user()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user)

For the registration function I think `wp_create_user()` will do the job for me. Again how much sanitization should i do?

Do i need to do the password hashing?

Also i have found some filters on the function reference page of the `wp_create_user()`. Those are `pre_user_user_pass`, `pre_user_user_login`, `pre_user_user_nicename` etc. Do, I need to use those filter before insert a new user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check my tutorial for front-end user registration and login in WordPress:
http://www.cozmoslabs.com/1012-wordpress-user-registration-template-and-custom-user-profile-fields/

As to the wp_signon, wp_insert_user, wp_create_user and wp_update_user they take care of all sanitation and validation of your content.

Also you don't need to use those filters in wp_create_user to create your users.